# Why does Docker ADD command not copy this file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In the file below, the file `apprequirements.txt` is ADDed to the container. I know because `pip install` works. However, the `myworker.py` file is not copied/added. **Why?**

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD ./frontend/apprequirements.txt /code
RUN pip install -r apprequirements.txt
ADD ./backend/myworker.py /code
```

I run this with docker-compose, you can see the whole example on https://github.com/AvidSoftware-be/Docker-compose-test

Comment: Is the `myworker.py` file in the `./backend/` folder?

Comment: Your example in github does not have a `backend` folder. Have you just made a path mistake?

Comment: I know but this is a work in progress, what I was doing is moving the app and myworker to separate folders but tis is not yet pushed as not to pollute the repo. However, I will push it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a  deep review  into your repo, this is my conclusion:

Your Dockerfile is fine, it does what is supposed to do. It creates an image, inside that image a folder `/code` was created and two files were copied `apprequirements.txt` and `myworker.py`.

Inside the `docker-compose.yml` file you have this line:

```
volumes:
  - ./frontend:/code
```

This means that after you run the `docker-compose up` command,
docker is going to mount a volumen over the `/code` existing directory.

The content of `/code` isn't removed from the container, however it is "masked", because the mounted directory is mounted on top of the existing files. The files are still in the container, but there are not reachable.

**Note:** the folder `./frontend` includes the file 'apprequirements.txt' is why you believe that only one file was added.

Comment: I know but this is a work in progress, what I was doing is moving the app and myworker to separate folders but tis is not yet pushed as not to pollute the repo. However, I will push it now.

Comment: I tested your Dockerfile and it looks like is working now, Still do you have problem moving the file into container? Still your question is valid?

Comment: If still you have problems moving the file, it could be a cache problem, you could try to build the image again using the flag `--no-cache`

Comment: No, still same problem. When I run this repo with "docker-compose up", I get  "ImportError: No module named myworker" from the frontend. Maybe I should inform you that I'm on OSX and hence the docker host is a VM? Maybe there is a difference with your setup? I installed 1.10.1a of the toolbox hoping this would solve it but no it does not.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough @HemersonVarela for pointing that out. I had a feeling something like that was happening. So, I gave it a thought and updated the repo to v0.3 https://github.com/AvidSoftware-be/docker-compose-test/tree/0.3 Now the whole test is working!!