# Docker run and volume clarification

Tags: docker

Below is my dockerfile, I do a copy of  js file in copy command and set working directory after that,followed by volume and run command.Below is my dockerfile
1) I understand node_modules(Which is created because of running npm install) IS getting wipedoff when container is first initialized because of create volume in the same location
  My quesion why my app.js which i copied in step 3 is not getting wiped of since its also on the same path as volume?

```
FROM node:latest

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV PORT=3000

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
VOLUME ["/app"]


RUN npm install

EXPOSE $PORT

ENTRYPOINT ["node","app.js"]
```

Comment: maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35466045/why-does-docker-add-command-not-copy-this-file/35468458#35468458

Comment: Two remarks: (i) regarding volumes, using the `VOLUME` command in a Dockerfile is actually a bad practice, see e.g. https://boxboat.com/2017/01/23/volumes-and-dockerfiles-dont-mix/ ; it is better to use the [-v or --mount flags of docker run](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag) instead (or appropriate options in a `docker-compose.yml` file); (ii) just copying all files in one go (`COPY . /app`) hinders Docker's cache mechanism; you could take a look at [this guide for dockerizing Node.js apps](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** Why is my app.js (which i copied in step 3) is not getting wiped off while `node_modules` is.

**A:** As explained in docker's documentation under the volume section.

**Quote:**

> Changing the volume from within the Dockerfile:
>
> **If any build steps**
> **change the data within the volume after it has been declared**, **those**
> **changes will be discarded.**

**Reference:** https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes

Comment: Perfect! I got the answer